# How to do parametrize the table name in a PDO statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

### Problem

I get a **PDO syntax error** when running a PDO statement where the **table name** is parametrized, like in

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM :table_name';
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':table_name' => "mytable"));
```

I could reproduce the problem with SELECT etc., so it's a general issue.
I tried to write it with backticks, with database name in front of it, a combination of both etc, nothing works.

### Question

How to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot parameterize table names, column names, or anything in an `IN` clause (it'll have to be bound separately). See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304) comment on [php.net](http://php.net).

See also: [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: I thought you could use bound parameters in an IN clause, so long as you bind each one seperately? Ie `IN (?)` won't work, but `IN (?, ?, ?)` should.

Comment: @andrewsi: you're right. I've updated the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is there a PDO maintainer that could fix this? It's a very common question and the solutions are always worryingly hacky due to a lack of an official method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameteterize table name with PDO and MySQLi prepared statements, because SQL server needs basic information to prepare the query before executing actual query.